# Display button in columns content Ext.grid.Panel with EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to developp an Ext.grid.Panel using EXT JS.
My need is to have a column where the content is a button.
obviously some think like this will not work

```
this.columns = [
        {
            text     : 'column1',
            width    : 120,
            sortable : true,
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'col1'
        },{
xtype: 'button',
width    : 120
}
//...
```

Also, I've tied some examples like this [one](http://techmix.net/blog/2010/11/25/add-button-to-extjs-gridpanel-cell-using-renderer/) but did not work for me.
Any leeds ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `componentcolumn` extension: http://skirtlesden.com/ux/component-column

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `actioncolumn` ([**Extjs docs**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action)) like that:

```
{
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 50,
        items: [{
            handler: function(grid) {
                alert("works");
            }
        }]
}
```

Comment: Yes i'v already tried this, but my need is to display a button there.
With the xtype solution, i've found just how to use icons.
unfortunately i'm looking for a button not and icon

Comment: I dont know if its possible to use a button. If it only needs to look like a button, you can use indeed an icon like here `http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/array-grid.html` Check out this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593732/add-textfield-and-button-for-grid-cell-edit-with-extjs`